# Make SwipeRefreshLayout animation invisible

Tags: android, listview, visibility, swiperefreshlayout, overscroll

If its possible make Swipe refresh layout animation fully invisible? I want to make whole animation (including loading and cricle with arrow when pulling down gesture) dissapear but I want to be able to use the onRefresh function. Maybe you know any alternatives that I can use in my listview (`OnScroll change listener` and `OverScroll` doesnt work for me accroding to trigger the bottom overscoll in my listview and I don wont to trigger my function when the list is swipe up and relase to scroll itself up - the Swipe refresh layout handle it very well for me)

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(NewActivity.this);
               swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        Log.i(TAG, "refresh");
    }
```

Update: According to yours hints I tried to implemented in several ways ( using only `setEnabled(false)` or `setRefreshing(false)` or both but in that case the onRefresh function didnt trigger at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use ..

**Edited**
From the documentation:

If an activity wishes to show just the progress animation, it should call setRefreshing(true). To disable the gesture and progress animation, call setEnabled(false) on the view.
So to show the animation:

```
swiprefreshLayout.setEnabled( true );
swiperefreshLayout.setRefreshing( true );
```

And to hide the animation:

```
swiperefreshLayout.setRefreshing( false );
swiprefreshLayout.setEnabled( false );
```

Comment: That did not solve my issue, I want to make whole animation invisible not dissapear it when its loading.